# UI Background from XML not shown corretly in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, layout

I'm working on this new project to support a friends gaming clan.

Ever since I've been working with Android Studio, this error never occurred and for a non-native English man, it's kinda hard to google this.

Whenever I'm setting drawable backgrounds or even background colors for layouts or any widgets in this project, 
they are not shown in-app!

[image: Background in XML Designer vs. in APP]

Very frustrating. There are no errors shown, neither in debug nor in the Android-Studio. I am using the same type of drawables in other projects.

Anyone got this before or has some advice?

PS: ProgressBar not showing is correct here!

Comment: can you show us code.

Comment: Post your XML Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little difficult to understand the question but let's see if I can help you

Try to set this Octopus logo in a ImageView, and this green colocar as the background of your layout. Something like this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:backgroundTint="YOUR_COLOR">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:src="@drawable/nice_octopus"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/your form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        ...

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Can you post your XML file? It's easier to help you

Comment: okay...im stupid...I set all the drawables as tools:background instead of android:background...something went wrong with my favourite attribute set.

Comment: hahaha. Try using android:background or android:backgroundTint to set a color as background of a view. This "tools:something" never worked for me

Comment: Yeah tools:something is just to preview UI when it's ment to be set dynamically :S

Answer (score 0):

You can try to update the studio or you can just do photoshop these layouts you can set a linearlayout with a background image and set editfield in it...